# How to link section tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi everyone I need help with sections I'm using section-container auto with deep_linking;true
i also have data-slug to each tabs,

I have 3 tabs with images on them so basically i want to have a direct link access to each individual tabs to have a link on the homepage. I tried adding location.hash script, also tried the .on click and .trigger, and none of them works.

thanks a lot.

```
<body>
<div class="section-container auto" data-section="" data-option="deep_linking;true;">
<section class="active">
<p class="title" data-section-title=""><a href="#tab1"></a><span>tab1</span></p>
<div class="content" data-slug="loans" data-section-content="">
<h1>tab1</h1></div>

<p class="title" data-section-title=""><a href="#tab2"><span>tab2</span></a></p>
<div class="content" data-slug="tab2" data-section-content="">
<h1>tab2</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply JF it, i included the code

Comment: I'm not seeing your script :/ can you provide that?

Comment: and a jsfiddle would be perfect. should be pretty easy to come up with solution if you provide more :)

Comment: @JF it i dont have any script, its pure html but a script would be helpful, im thinking of when a page loads it check the url if what tab  was navigated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done it guys, i just added a script:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('section').removeClass('active');
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash !== '')
    { 
          $('section'+hash).addClass('active');
    }         
});
```

it checks the hash in the url then sets the section class="Active".
thanks guys for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

this is the The simplest way >>>>>> try  this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="section-container auto" data-section="" data-option="deep_linking;true;">
<section class="active">
<p class="title" data-section-title=""><a id="tab1" href="#tab1"><span>tab1</span></a>    </p>
<div class="content" data-slug="loans" data-section-content="" id="panel1">
<h1>tab1</h1></div>

<p class="title" data-section-title=""><a id="tab2" href="#tab2"><span>tab2</span></a></p>
<div class="content" data-slug="tab2" data-section-content="" id="panel2">
<h1>tab2</h1>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#panel1').hide(); 
    $('#panel2').hide(); 

    $('#tab1').click(function(){
       $('#panel1').show(); 
        $('#panel2').hide(); 
    });

    $('#tab2').click(function(){
       $('#panel2').show(); 
        $('#panel1').hide(); 
    });



});
```

**Demo** : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoudSarhan/5Lscg/1/)

Comment: thanks, but what i need is to have a direct link to the tabs like "http://foo.com/tabs#tab2"

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery UI library to make tabs and panels

try this code to figure out what is jquery ui tabs :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>tabs demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1">
    <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
    <pre><code>$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); </code></pre>
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-2">

  </div>
  <div id="fragment-3">

  </div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

to watch  how it's look like see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoudSarhan/493dK/)

for complete reference see [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: thanks for the reply mahmoud, is there any script for my current coding, because changing the codes will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms your markup would be a `<ul>` with your tabs, followed by a stack of containers for the content of those tabs. You current markup has them inside the same container, which is going to make the effect hard to pull off.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab1">Tab Title</li>
    <li class="tab2">Tab Title2</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <p class="tab1">Content for tab 1</p>
    <p class="tab2">Content for tab 2</p>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc7mq/) -- tweak the CSS as you see fit, but you really don't need JQuery UI just to build tabs.